# Changing sign of a 64 bit floating point number in verilog?

Tags: verilog

So I am working with 64 bit floating point numbers in Verilog for synthesis, ideally I would like to do -A*B, where A and B are the two numbers. I have got past doing A*B, so is it okay now if I just change the value of the first bit 0 to 1 or 1 to 0 to make it represent -A*B.

kinda like,

A[0]=~A[0];

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes! That's all there is to it.

Keep in mind that negating `0` will give you `-0`. (They're different floating-point bit patterns.) Whether this matters to you will depend on your application.

Comment: Ideally there might be 0's in the program. What effect could a -0 have in the program if I were to add or multiply it with another FP number later on?

Comment: @user2045143: `-0 * x` is `-0` for all finite `x`.  `-0 + x` is the same as `+0 + x` (assuming default rounding).